# Event participants registrations expires for participants that decide to pay later with cash

Tags: paylater, online-registration

We offer event registration where the participant can register and pay later with cash.
However when participants choose to register and pay later, thus on participant status "Pending payment later", CiviCRM simply expires their registration after 24 hours. We are running version 4.6.20 on Drupal 7. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can solve it?
In the meantime I have set the "waiting list" to zero should in case this is triggering the expiration of the registered participants. This setting was previously set to 24 hours. It will be weird if the Event waiting list is automatically expiring registered participants who are in status "Pending Payment Later. I need your brilliant brains. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

This is a configurable option in the event settings.  Go to **Events menu » Manage Events**, click **Configure menu » Online Registration** next to the event in question, and put a "0" in the "Pending participant expiration (hours)" box to disable this.  See screenshot:
[image]